# How to Action chain using ActionSequence inWebdriverjs Javascript Nodejs ActionSequence?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am chaining my action of clicking Navigation Menu and for that purpose I am trying to use this ActionSequence Class in Javascript/NodeJs Selenium Automation. I know there is fairly straight forward way of action chaining in Java. Is this the analogous thing in Javascript. How do i use this? Below is the Documentation, i referred to and the code i tried. Can somebody write the exact way to write it down not a one line to make it work. I tried several ways and none worked for me. I may be making some silly mistake since i am not familiar a lot with ins and out of javascript selenium.

Class ActionSequence
Class for defining sequences of complex user interactions. Each sequence will not be executed until {@link #perform} is called.

Example:

```
 new ActionSequence(driver).
     keyDown(Key.SHIFT).
     click(element1).
     click(element2).
     dragAndDrop(element3, element4).
     keyUp(Key.SHIFT).
     perform();
```

This is the documentation of ActionSequence.

How do i use this class ? Is this the latest thing for action chaining to be used in Javascript Selenium ? If there is something new please show me that.

I have tried to use this inside async function :

```
  let actionSequence = new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver);

  await  actionSequence
    .mouseMove(NavElementArray[0][1])
    .mouseMove(NavElementArray[2][1])
    .click()
    .perform();
```

Am i defining actionSequence or using the correct way. Error' webdriver.ActionSequence is not a constructor'

Please do not put answer on how to do it in Java or other bindings. Just stick to Javascript NodeJs webdriverjs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

not sure which version you're using but 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_LegacyActionSequence.html
appears deprecated

try importing/new LegacyActions(driver).chain1().chain2()...chainN().perform()

Comment: Yes I see LegacyActionSequence is deprecated. Do you know how to use the Actions in ActionSequence though? I am using latest selenium webdriverjs

Comment: exactly how you're doing it, but i'd try the LegacyActions class instead

Comment: got same error: TypeError: webdriver.LegacyActionSequence is not a constructor when i replaced ActionSequence with LegacyActionSequence.@nacmonad

Answer (score 0):

Added 3 lines in the index.js file in node-modules/selenium-webdriver of my project.

```
const actions = require('./lib/actions');
```

after the first long list of const declarations

```
const LegacyActionSequence = actions.LegacyActionSequence;
```

after the next smaller list of declarations

```
exports.LegacyActionSequence=actions.LegacyActionSequence;
```

at the end of the exports list at the end of the file.

My code,

```
await new LegacyActionSequence(driver)
.mouseMove(element,{x:0,y:0})
.perform()
```

earlier was showing

```
TypeError: LegacyActionSequence is not a constructor
```

Working smoothly, for now.

Comment: Tried this approach.  There is no error, but no action happening on the UI.  Using chrome browser version 80.0